# Display two series with Dygraph in React

Tags: reactjs, dygraphs

I would like to display 2 series in dygraph but i do not know how to do, thank you for your help.

Here is my code:

```js
    let datas = [];

    datas = state.logDatas.data;

        new Dygraph (
            'Two_series',
            datas,
            {
                labels: ["key", "value"],
                title: "",
                width: 1000,
                height: 400,
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found, example tab "datas" for two series :

```js
[
  [1, null, 3],
  [2, 2, null],
  [3, null, 7],
  [4, 6, null],
  [5, null, 5],
  [6, 4, null]
]
```